# Java's readInt() equivalent in C?

Tags: java, c, linux, sockets, inputstream

In one side I have a Java client writing ints into its outputstream:

```
int a = 20;
dataout.writeInt(a);
dataout.flush();
```

From the other side I have a C server listening the connection:

```
int client = accept(...);
```

How to read the int sent by Java?

If I had a Java server, i could easily write:

```
int a = dataIn.readInt();
```

How to do this in C?

thanks

Comment: Will depend on the endianess of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it into a char buffer and use `atoi()` to convert the string into a int.

Comment: assuming an integer as 4 bytes, is this what you mean?
char buf[4];
read(client, buf, 4);
int integer = atoi(buf);

Comment: Not quite - if the Java server is sending the Int as four bytes, the whole thing is going to get a lot more complicated as you basically need to know exactly in what byte order the Int is sent. I would try to send Int as a string, use a somewhat bigger buffer (16 bytes up) to store the string in and then use atoi as you suggested. If you're sending the Int as a byte representation, I would convert it to network byte order before sending and convert it back to host order once you received it, otherwise you're in a world of really odd bugs.

Comment: atoi has no error-handling, atoi("0") == atoi("blah"); better you use strtol

Answer (score 0):

You can use the read function, but you have to be careful to consume sizeof(int) chars from the socket and then you have to worry about endianess.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` should work if you don't mind sending in plain text:

```
fscanf(dataIn, "%d", &a);
```

Plain text rules :-)
Just be sure to send a '\n' (or something not a digit) from the source before the flush.